# Maxima and minima of $x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus

I was considering about infinitely many maxima and minima of $x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ on $(0,1)$. It seems easy to see this by graph but I'm not getting there in order to prove this by $f'(x)=0$. Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You cannot find the exact maxima and minima because $f'(x)=0$ has no analytic solution.

Comment: Yes. I'm stuck in solving f'(x)=0

Comment: @copper.hat I want to prove this by putting f' =0 but I'm stuck.

Comment: Are we talking about relative extrema or absolute extrema? Because we have a single absolute minimum on that interval.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

You seem to be asking to show that $x\sin(1/x)$ has an infinite number of relative extrema on $(0,1)$. If you let $f(x) = x\sin\left(x^{-1}\right)$, then 
$$
f'(x)
 = \sin\left(x^{-1}\right) + x \cos\left(x^{-1}\right) \frac{-1}{x^2}
 = \sin\left(x^{-1}\right) - \frac{\cos\left(x^{-1}\right)}{x}
$$
So setting $f'(x) = 0$ yields
$$
\tan\left(x^{-1}\right) = x^{-1},
$$
can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm not sure about the solution except infinity. Plese help further.

Comment: @Ashok Try looking at $\tan(x)=x$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Can this be seen analytically? Graphically it looks great.

Comment: @Ashok Just note that the tangent function is periodic and that every "branch" is surjective on $\mathbb R$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Thank you very much. My doubt is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\dfrac1x$.

The derivative of

$$\frac{\sin(t)}t$$ is

$$\frac{t\cos(t)-\sin(t)}{t^2}.$$

As $t\cos(t)$ is oscillatory, when $|t|>1$, it crosses the range $[-1,1]$ on every half-period of the cosine, where it meets the sine, and there are infinitely many intersections.

[image]